# Rewriting Wizard game of Land of Lisp in Clojure

Tags: clojure, jvm, lisp, land-of-lisp

I'm trying to rewrite the Wizard game from "Land of Lisp"    http://landoflisp.com/wizards_game.lisp

```
(def *nodes* {:living-room "you are in the living-room. a wizard is snoring loudly on the couch."
          :garden "you are in a beautiful garden. there is a well in front of you."
          :attic "you are in the attic. there is a giant welding torch in the corner."})

(def *edges* {:living-room '((garden west door) (attic upstairs ladder))
          :garden '(living-room east door)
          :attic '(living-room downstairs ladder)})

(defn describe-location [location nodes]
  (nodes location))

(defn describe-path-raw [edge]
  `(there is a ~(last edge) going ~(second edge) from here.))

(defn describe-path [edge]
   (map #(symbol (name %)) (describe-path-raw edge)))

(defn describe-paths [location edges]
   (apply concat (map describe-path-raw (location edges))))
```

When trying:

```
   (println (describe-paths :attic *edges*))
```

I got this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol (wizard-game.clj:0)

I don't have a Lispy eye yet, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Putting this into a REPL, and running trace:

```
user> (ns foo (:use clojure.contrib.trace))
nil
```

At this point I copy in your code into the REPL. (not shown)

Next, I run a trace:

```
foo> (dotrace [describe-location describe-path-raw describe-path describe-paths]
              (describe-paths :attic *edges*))
TRACE t1662: (describe-paths :attic {:living-room ((garden west door) (attic upstairs ladder)),     :garden (living-room east door), :attic (living-room downstairs ladder)})
TRACE t1663: |    (describe-path-raw living-room)
; Evaluation aborted.
foo>
```

So the problem is (describe-path-raw living-room).  As the error message points out, living-room is a symbol, and this function is trying to do things like call last and second on it, which can only be done on sequences.

**So why is this happening?**

Inside of describe-paths, you are calling (location edges). Here, location is :attic, and edges is a map.  Therefore, (location edges) works out to (living-room downstairs ladder).  You are mapping describe-path-raw onto this list, which works out to:

```
((describe-path-raw living-room) (describe-path-raw downstairs) (describe-path-raw ladder))
```

And this is throwing an exception on the first call, since living-room is a symbol, not a sequence.

Comment: Why the call is becoming: (describe-path-raw living-room) ? :attic has value of list type.

Comment: @4bu3li: See the addition to my answer.  I hope this helps.

Comment: attic is mapped to a list. I mean this is a list, right? '(living-room downstairs ladder) ? I run this code: (class (:attic '(living-room downstairs ladder))) which returns PersistentList. I solved the issue, thanks to you and seh but I still didn't get the real problem.

Comment: @4bu3li: That is a list, correct.  It is returned by (location edges), inside of the describe-paths function.  But then describe-paths calls map describe-path-raw onto that list.  What does that do?  It applies describe-path-raw onto every element in that list.  The first element in that list is living-room, and therefore, the first function call for evaluating (map describe-path-raw living-room) is (describe-path-raw living-room).  And living-room is a symbol, which is not what describe-path-raw requires.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `describe-paths` expects that the value looked up in the `*edges*` map will be a list of lists, not just a list. Note the difference between the `:living-room` entry and the `:garden` and `:attic` entries: the former has a top-level spine below which you find two three-tuples, whereas the latter two each have just one three-tuple.

Function `describe-path-raw` expects to receive a tuple of at least size two, but it really only makes sense here for those of size three; feeding it any of the four three-tuples in the `*edges*` map will work. The problem you ran into is due to applying `map` to the `*edges*` entry for `:attic`, which takes the list

```
(living-room downstairs ladder)
```

and feeds the list objects one-by-one to `describe-path-raw`:

```
(describe-path-raw living-room)
(describe-path-raw downstairs)
(describe-path-raw ladder)
```

In each of those three forms, the argument passed to `describe-path-raw` is a symbol, rather than the list expected by `describe-path-raw`.

In short, try adding an extra set of parentheses around the second two values in your `*edges*` map, nesting each list within a new top-level list.